# TCPDF How To set Page Size For Zebra Printer Sticker Label Size 2 inch X 1 Inch

Tags: php, tcpdf

Please Guide iam using zebra printer and sticker size is  width 2inch and height 1inch how set this size in TCPDF PHP

My Code using but page is not generate this size Image Attached

```
$width = 2;
$height = 1;
$pageLayout = array($width, $height);
$pdf = new TCPDF('p', 'in', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Output Page Image:

[image]

Sticker Image:

[image]